# PL/SQL: What is ERROR: ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers

Tags: sql, plsql

Hello i have some problems to do a pl/sql trigger . I want to do a trigger that do a "history". I create a table that i record the sout of the trigger with this code:

```
create table control(
camp1 varchar2(255) 
);
```

It doesn't works yet but we are close.
Now with help of user:7623856 when i execute this is what appears
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHLIC.png) I work in SQL Developer and oracle 11

This is the new code

```
create or replace trigger t_auditar_alta_empleat
after insert on empleats
for each row
begin
  if :new.codi_dept is null then 
  insert into control values('Alta empleat amb codi' || :new.codi_emp);
  else
  insert into control values('Alta empleat amb codi' || :new.codi_emp || 'amb el codi de departament '|| new:codi_dept);
  end if;
end;
```

And appears a new error.

*LINE/COL  ERROR

5/3       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
5/109     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'CODI_DEPT'
5/109     PL/SQL: ORA-00917: missing comma
Errores: comprobar log de compilador*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your almost there, but as defined you current have a statement level trigger, but you need a row level trigger. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374).

```
create or replace trigger t_auditar_alta_empleat
after insert on empleats
for each row        -- added 
begin
  if :new.codi_dept is null then 
  insert into control values('Alta empleat amb codi' || :new.codi_emp);
  else
  insert into control values('Alta empleat amb codi' || :new.codi_emp || 'amb el codi de departament '|| new:codi_dept);
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: thanks for your help but now there are another problem

Comment: That's just a syntax error. On the second insert "new:codi_dept" should be ":new.codi_dept"